# How to test responsive in react testing library and jest dom

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test responsive behavior of a component with react-testing-library and jest dom. The media query for the code being tested is working correctly in the browser. This is what I have for the setup...

```
 beforeAll(() => {
      window.resizeTo(767, 500);
    });

    it('should have correct styling for mobile', async () => {
      const {findByTestId} = render(
        <StepHeader index={1}>Future Step</StepHeader>,
      );

      console.log(window.innerWidth)
      const stepHeader = await findByTestId('step-header-button-1'); //the element has this test id on it.
      expect(stepHeader).toHaveStyle({fontSize: '16px', height: '48px'});
    });
```

The console log shows that the screen width is indeed what I expect it to be. But the test is not passing, it's actually picking up the styling for desktop, for instance the height of `36px` instead of 48. What is the better way of testing responsive screens in react-testing library and jest-dom? Am I resizing the screen correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if there's a solution, but there may be some leads in [this GH issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media/issues/93).